# Working with 2 json arrays with connected data via ID

Tags: php, arrays, json

Been trying to work with two arrays and extract information from the arrays. I can do this with the foreach but I have linked file references (an ID)  which targets data in another array.

Array 1 -

```
Array
(
    [type] => land
    [id] => 0b1b522e-0cd2-4880-b3ac-a5d86bc2e837       
    [relationships] => Array
        (
            [address] => Array
                (
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => address
                            [id] => bb89e6c3-9114-4192-a0a7-82c08402d36e
                        )

                )
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => details
                            [id] => f8f0e489-bb86-4857-a815-ab6338d90f26
                        )

                )
            [lettingsListing] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 
                )

            [primaryImage] => Array
                (
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => media
                            [id] => 58574088-01a2-45da-a66e-cd3ce1741377
                        )
                )
            [images] => Array
                (
                    [data] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => media
                                    [id] => 58574088-01a2-45da-a66e-cd3ce1741377
                                )
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => media
                                    [id] => 32d9d605-d55d-48b7-aa62-5e22f762f165
                                )
                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => media
                                    [id] => c879656a-a34f-4c93-b6c7-49d3c7b11804
                                )
                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => media
                                    [id] => 434f8d79-df19-474d-a275-6c9a5fb0985b
                                )
                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => media
                                    [id] => cefccee0-cd30-4c69-9f6f-2bd76116a619
                                )
                            [5] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => media
                                    [id] => c0377f6c-4279-4176-a5bd-0190b7fd97a8
                                )
                            [6] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => media
                                    [id] => 6869c65a-bb55-4b9f-8dc1-71ffa5eb84dc
                                )
                            [7] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => media
                                    [id] => c9b13725-059a-4c96-a8fd-77c9fc9fe05f
                                )
                            [8] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => media
                                    [id] => edbdddb2-afc7-43ab-9a79-94e0e8e63597
                                )
                            [9] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => media
                                    [id] => 320de2d7-6ecd-4ec7-9250-f72e228be8a7
                                )
                            [10] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => media
                                    [id] => 63daaccf-d8d2-4b55-aece-5a01e379fba0
                                )
                            [11] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => media
                                    [id] => 5d2c253a-03f5-4ea0-b06d-dd17c80d5f3b
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

The images in the array are like:

```
[0] => Array
            (
                [type] => media
                [id] => 58574088-01a2-45da-a66e-cd3ce1741377
            )
```

The ID then corresponds to another array (array 2)

```
Array
(
    [type] => media
    [id] => 58574088-01a2-45da-a66e-cd3ce1741377
    [attributes] => Array
        (
            [name] => p048205_01
            [order] => 1
            [is_featured] => 
            [feature_index] => 
            [title] => 
            [is_image] => 1
            [url] => ***urlhere***
                )
        )
)
```

So my question is how to get the associated data ([url]) with each ID from the other array. I thought about array_merge but that did not help. My only other thinking is to do a foreach inside the current loop but I have heard it best to not to that?

Comment: I would convert the images array (array2) so it has the `id` as the key, then your job is simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new array to hold the image urls from what you called array2, but which has the `id` as the key, so you can jump straight to the URL from your other foreach loop.

```
$img_urls = []
foreach( $array2 as $a ) {
    $img_urls[$a['id']] = $a;
}
```

Or if you only want the url in this new array

```
$img_urls = []
foreach( $array2 as $a ) {
    $img_urls[$a['id']] = $a['attributes']['url'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As RiggsFolly said, you need to manipulate the second array with images like this:

```
$new_arr_images = [];

foreach ($arr_images as $value) {
   $new_arr_images[$value['id']] = $value['attributes']['url'];
}

// then loop through first array and populate it with image urls based on the ID
```